# Layout works in jsfiddle, not in browser

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

Link to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Uy4Jz/
I am trying to make a layout using jQuery UI tabs and the tutorial here (http://stugreenham.com/demos/fluid-width-with-a-fixed-sidebar/), but for some reason it only works in a jsfiddle (in the browser both the sidebar and content take up the whole width of the page with only plain white backgrounds). The added CSS in the jsfiddle is located near the bottom and is this in the actual CSS file:

```
html {
overflow: hidden;
}

#sidebar {
background: #000000;
float: left;
left: 300px;
margin-left: -300px;
position: relative;
width: 300px;
overflow-y: auto;
color: #FFFFFF;
}

#contentWrapper {
float: left;
width: 100%;
} 

#content {
background: #0A0000;
margin-left: 300px;
overflow-y: auto;
}
```

And here is the actual HTML file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset = "utf-8">
<title>Me</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    //GET BROWSER WINDOW HEIGHT
    var currHeight = $(window).height();
    //SET HEIGHT OF SIDEBAR AND CONTENT ELEMENTS
    $('#sidebar, #content').css('height', currHeight);
    //ON RESIZE OF WINDOW
    $(window).resize(function() {
        //GET NEW HEIGHT
        var currHeight = $(window).height();
        //RESIZE BOTH ELEMENTS
        $('#sidebar, #content').css('height', currHeight);
    });
    $('#tabs').tabs();
});
</script>
<link href = "jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css">
</head>
<body>
<header id = "sidebar">
    This is the sidebar. Hopefully it works.
</header>
<article id = "contentWrapper">
<section id = "content">
    <div id = "tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href = "#tabs-1">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#tabs-2">About Me</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#tabs-3">My Projects</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id = "tabs-1">
            <p>Y HELLO THAR</p>
        </div>
        <div id = "tabs-2">
            <p>I am a person.</p>
        </div>
        <div id = "tabs-3">
            <p>I like to do things sometimes.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</article>
</body>
</html>
```

I think the problem is that the CSS isn't applying properly to the two main layout elements, but I don't know why.

Edit: On quick inspection using Chrome's developer tools, my suspicions are confirmed: no matched CSS is shown for the two main elements. Why is this?

Comment: Why are you using `header`, `article`, and `section`?

Comment: It wasn't working with div either, and I thought following the tutorial exactly would be the way to go.

Edit: Just changed all of those to divs, and the problem still exists.

Comment: That site is referencing a very outdated version of jQuery (1.5). I suggest using jQueryUI example instead: http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#vertical

Comment: But it's referencing 2.0.2, and I don't intend for the tabs to be vertical (the squished nature of jsfiddle just makes that happen).

Comment: what are u trying to do?

Comment: Create a layout similar to the one linked above with the tabs in the content section.

Comment: Are there whitespaces in your document before the `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`? If so, remove them.

Comment: are you using a custom stylesheet? are you declaring that in the head of your html document?

Comment: You can see the stylesheet declaration in the HTML I provided (below the scripts), and there aren't any spaces before the doctype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was editing a duplicate of the actual CSS file, not the real thing. Thanks everyone for the help, though.